# Auto expandable rows and subrows react table using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here I have code of react table using hooks, and i have struggled on task where I need to set all rows and subrows expanded by default when i open the page, I have tried several solutions, but all of them didn't work.

Link to the code : https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/expanding

Comment: It looks like that `react-table` has an option `initialState.expanded` to pass to `useTable`. https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/b1b71103c4be32e16a9c9886d685008a33fd6dd6/docs/api/useExpanded.md#table-options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as I said, the option `initialState.expanded` allows you to expand the rows you want.

```
useTable(
    {
      columns: userColumns,
      data,
      initialState: {
        expanded: { "0": true, "2": true }
      }
    },
    useExpanded // Use the useExpanded plugin hook
  )
```

This will expand the first and the third row.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your respond, really appreciate, and how can I make SUBROWS expandable in this case, do not you know? Cause decision above makes expandable only rows, but now subrows. For example, at the sandbox I have subrows for each row, and I need to expand all of them until the last child. Thanks!

Comment: and I cannot do like that : initialState: {
        expanded: {
          0: true,
          0.1: true,
          0.1.0: true,
        },
      },
      },

Comment: You should do something like `expanded: { 0: true, 0.1: true, 0.1.0: true, }`, maybe you need to do a loop that go through each child to build the object `expanded` with all your rows/subrows. You don't have many choices, when you choose to use a library you are limited to its limits.